# Formatting a value using a formatting string not working in getter

Tags: c#

I have a class with properties RealValue, OutputFormat and SsrsValue. RealValue represents a value that can be of any type and OutputFormat is a string that represents formatting value. SsrsValue returns a string that is basically RealValue formatted using OutputFormat.

This is the getter for SsrsValue:

```
public virtual string SsrsValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OutputFormat))
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", RealValue, OutputFormat);
            }
            switch (RealValue)
            {
                case bool boolValue:
                    return boolValue ? "1" : "0";
                case DateTime dateTime:
                    return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                default:
                    return RealValue.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the usage of property in action:

```
var reportToShow = reportClient.GetReport<ZaehllisteReport>(new IfbReportParameter<DateTime>(ReportParameters.Zaehlliste.Datum, DateTime.Today, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

So if I pass a value of *15.12.2020 00:00:00*, then the getter of SsrsValue should return *15/12/2020*.

Instead, what I get here is this:

[image]

I didn't work much with string.Format in the past, so maybe my usage is incorrect. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The line `string.Format("{0} {1}", RealValue, OutputFormat);` is the culprit, I suspect? You're literally asking `string.Format` to print `RealValue`, followed by the value of `OutputFormat`: nothing in there is asking it to format `RealValue` *using* `OutputFormat` as the format string. I suspect what you want to do is `RealValue.ToString(OutputFormat)`

Comment: @canton7 RealValue can be of any type, not just DateTime...so .ToString() will not accept format as a parameter.

Comment: This is why it's important to post a [mcve]: I can't tell the data type of `RealValue` by looking at your code! You probably want to test whether it implements `IFormattable` then: `RealValue is IFormattable formattable ? formattable.ToString(OutputFormat, null) : RealValue.ToString()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

I think @canton7 is correct on the `string.Format()` line so try the following:

```
get
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OutputFormat))
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(RealValue, out DateTime dateValue);
        return dateValue.ToString(OutputFormat);
    }
    switch (RealValue)
    {
        case bool boolValue:
            return boolValue ? "1" : "0";
        case DateTime dateTime:
            return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        default:
            return RealValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Solution is parsing the value back to a `DateTime` and reformatting it with the specified output format.

Comment: I don't think this is correct: it looks like `RealValue` can *be* a `DateTime`, rather than a string which can be parsed to a `DateTime`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to return a formatted string of an arbitrary type. When the `OutputFormat` parameter is supplied, you apply `string.Format`, otherwise you apply type-specific logic. In the case of a DateTime, you provide the default format string "dd/MM/yyyy".

To make your code work the way you want, you want it to fall through to the `case DateTime dateTime:` statement. You can do this by simply providing `null` as the value for the `OutputFormat` parameter in the usage snippet you provided:

```cs
var reportToShow = reportClient.GetReport<ZaehllisteReport>(new IfbReportParameter<DateTime>(ReportParameters.Zaehlliste.Datum, DateTime.Today, null));
```

This way the `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OutputFormat))` block will be skipped and the `switch` statement takes over.

---

If I may add my thoughts on how to improve your code, I'd probably do away with the `if` statement altogether.

```cs
get
{
   switch (RealValue)
   {
      case bool boolValue:
         return boolValue ? "1" : "0";
      case DateTime dateTime:
         return dateTime.ToString(OutputFormat ?? "dd/MM/yyyy");
      default:
         return RealValue.ToString();
   }
}
```

This code will work for booleans (returning "1" or "0"), DateTimes (returning the date wither formatted using OutputFormat or (if OutputFormat is null) using the default format string "dd/MM/yyyy" and for everything else (returning whatever `ToString` returns).

You can easily expand the `switch` statement to handle more specific cases.